# Can we show both Credit Card Statement and Bank statement for Schengen visa?

Tags: payment-cards, proof-of-funds, schengen-visas

I am planning to visit France in September. According to the requirement list the embassy is asking for a bank statement. I would like to know how much should I show in my account for 6 days in France. Is it possible to show credit card statement (planning to buy air tickets by credit card) and other fixed deposits?

Comment: Both credit card statements and bank statements are acceptable evidence for *Schengen* applications.  See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45648/can-i-convince-embassies-to-accept-my-overpaid-credit-card-as-a-proof-of-funds/45681#45681

Comment: A credit card statement is only of secondary use; the primary reason they ask for a bank statement is because it also indicates that your financial status is commensurate with what you have listed as your job; that you have steady income (and expenses). A credit card statement doesn't show all this.

Answer (score 6):

They don't just want to see the balance of your account, they want to see a reasonable **pattern** of income and expenditure. For tourism, you should have enough monthly income to pay for a normal cost of living **and** to save for the trip.

- This shows that you have a steady and well-paid job back home, which makes you less *likely* to become an illegal immigrant and overstay.
- It shows that you did not need a credit to make the trip. People who borrow large amounts of money might plan to repay it by working in Europe.

Answer (score 1):

Well, credit card statements might be acceptable in most countries. I have just checked with Schengen consulates in my country (Pakistan) just credit card statements are not acceptable. Further they stated that having a good credit line available along with 6 months bank statements would enhance your financial and economic conditions. [immihelp](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/means-of-substinence.html) mention: *Acceptable means of subsistence may be cash, traveler's checks, credit cards or anything else that guarantees sufficient funds.*

Most France Embassies required somewhere  at least [€60](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/means-of-substinence.html) for each day of stay. You are staying for six days, presumably somewhere around €360 to €400 plus cost of your airline ticket should be available. From my personal perspective at least €2,000 would satisfy the visa officer provided that you are maintaining your accounts nicely for the last 6 months.

So basically more or less Schengen requirements are almost the same, but differ in some countries depending on your nationality.