# Is a credit card "proof of sufficient funds" to enter Ukraine?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, payment-cards, proof-of-funds

The US State Department website has the following listed as an [entry requirement](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/ukraine.html) for Ukraine:

> You must provide proof of ... sufficient funds for the duration of your stay.

If I were asked at Ukraine Immigration for proof of funds, would it suffice to show a credit card?

(This is specifically about showing proof of funds when requested by an immigration officer, not for a visa.)

Comment: I've only ever shown bank statements before, but since my statements are over six months old now, I'd like to know if a credit card is a valid alternative since the statements aren't really "recent" anymore.

Comment: The bank statements are used to verify if you have strong ties to your home country, not just to verify if you have sufficient funds. If you get 2000EUR per month in the account from the same payer then you probably have a stable job of some sort. If you got 10000EUR a week before submitting the statement and had 0 up until then, then this indicates fund parking and raises red flags all over the place. Check this: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105?s=1|0.0000#66105

Comment: I believe this varies drastically with the country.  In the case of arriving at the USA: (i) it is rarely even checked (ii) in a sense, sure cards are fine but (iii) it is utterly at the discretion of the officer {ideas like 'available funds' are more an excuse or rationale the officer can choose, in a totally arbitrary judgement call}.  For say Ukraine, I'm sure the paradigm is totally different.

Comment: ... I have no job so that's not going to help much. :)

Comment: If you specifically want to know about Ukraine, and that's fair enough, you should I'd say put that right in the title.  This issue is very specific to the from-to travel pair you know?

Comment: I allowed myself to add Ukraine to the head question, as it does depend on the country, as Joe explained.

Comment: The one time I as asked for proof of funds was when entering Malaysia for the first time. They also wanted to see my onward ticket to Yangon, and the visa for Myanmar, and the onward ticket from Yangon to Bangkok, plus my hostel booking in Malaysia. The second time I came to Malaysia there was no such craziness so I dont exactly know what triggers such a request.

Comment: And if you want to make thus specific to Ukraine that's cool but that means I'll be opening another half dozen questions in the next month or two ask I keep travelling. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I convince embassies to accept my overpaid credit card as a proof of funds?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45648/can-i-convince-embassies-to-accept-my-overpaid-credit-card-as-a-proof-of-funds)

Comment: A credit card proves nothing at all. For all they know, it's maxed out  and gives you access to zero funds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/ukraine/entry-requirements) Website:

> The Ukrainian authorities accept the following as a proof of sufficient funds: cash, **bank cards along with bank statements**, accommodation bookings, tourist vouchers, a letter from the person or company you’re visiting stating that they will cover your expenses, **a return ticket or onward travel ticket**.

The Ukrainian border agency website does not specify acceptable proof of funds; however, based on the GOV.UK info, a return or onward ticket should be accepted for this purpose.

Besides, no matter what some websites say, it is **rare** for them to ask a single question (in fact, most of them speak very little to no English). They just scan your passport, check the databases, possibly ask where you're going, and then stamp the passport (or migration Card if you choose to fill one out)

Comment: Fascinating, so it's "much like the USA, say" .... pretty minimal/cursory checking as a rule?

Comment: @JoeBlow Like the US for US citizens/perm. residents perhaps. As a VWP national I've always been questioned quite extensively (including when using APC), but never asked to show onward tickets, my rental contract, bank statements, Hotel Reservation etc. And thank Lord for that, because I just cannot bother to bring a pile of documents on my trips - I'd rather be sent to secondary and show them things online if it should boil down to that in the future