# Instead of bank statement, can I provide brokerage statement?

Tags: visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, portugal

I'm a citizen of a non-EU/US country. For an application for a Portuguese D7 residence visa, I am required to provide bank statements, signed and sealed, according to the information on the embassy's website

**Main question:** Since I keep little money in any bank, can I provide brokerage statements instead?

**Side questions:**

Would it be a problem if my broker is US based? Address on the statement is local and its where I reside. The broker is a publicly listed company.

Can this document be virtual somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) The information in that question is general, not specific to the UK. In short, the statements are needed to document your lifestyle based on a history of your cash flows. A particular balance is not all that interesting.

Comment: Your bank statement might prove you have regular income

Comment: It depends a lot on your exact situation, but your best bet is probably to provide both, like you can (and often should) include savings accounts. Immigration officers love people with a lot of money they are willing to spend. But remember that you must prove you want to leave the country you are applying to visit, and that often includes proving that you have a job and regular income, and that is more likely to be visible on your bank account statement.

Comment: @user120504 It might depend on the purpose for which bank statements are required. If the objective is to demonstrate net worth to meet a particular eligibility criteria, a brokerage statement might suffice. If the purpose is to demonstrate liquid assets, or regular income, it may not be acceptable. In any event, without knowing the country concerned it’s probably impossible to give a reliable answer to your question.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45648/can-i-convince-embassies-to-accept-my-overpaid-credit-card-as-a-proof-of-funds

Comment: Considering your goal, your question should really be on expatriates.  https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please don’t use the edit function to simply replace a question with an entirely different one (*especially* after an answer has been received). If you have a new question, you should submit it *as* a new question.

Comment: In fact, it appears the “new” question wasn’t a new question at all, but was copy-pasted in its entirety from the suggested duplicate.

Comment: You also shouldn’t be removing information that’s necessary for the question to be answerable…

Comment: Locked to stop editing. I am not going to migrate a question with this kind of edit history. Please ask a new question on Expatriates Stack Exchange if you need more information.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the bank statements is not only to tell immigration how much money you have, but also what your regular day to day finances are like. Unless you are using your broker for day to day transactions broker statements are not sufficient on their own. However if you keep substantial savings in your brokerage there is nothing to stop you submitting brokerage statements *in addition* to your bank statements.

Comment: It means things like paying your rent, your bills, paying for food, clothes, gasoline for your car,  things like that. Also they expect to see your income deposited to an account.

Comment: @user120504 Not necessarily...but maybe. Read [this Travel.SE question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab). If you use your credit card regularly, you may wish to also include card statements so the ECO has a more complete picture of how your finances operate.

Comment: "One is me depositing cash from another account" - then they will possibly be interested in the statement for _that_ account also